# PostgreSQL query changes plan

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I have a PostgreSQL query which has a With clause(CTE) where the input values are given(int datatype). For this query the number of output rows will be same as that of the number of input values that is given in inside this With clause. There is no join in the with clause, there are only two tables in the main select clause.

This query executes in less than 500 milliseconds until the number of input values are 531. If it goes beyond that it takes around 15 seconds.(even for 532 input values).

In Explain plan I could see the plan changes for the main query from "Nested loop left join" to "Hash right join" when the number of input values exceeds 531.

Edit: have added explain analyze for both scenarios.

If the number of input values is 532

```
Sort  (cost=45221.67..45221.68 rows=2 width=322) (actual time=15371.553..15371.576 rows=532 loops=1)
  Sort Key: fc.flashnumber DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 95kB
  CTE t
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..4489.54 rows=3586 width=22) (actual time=3.876..21.531 rows=532 loops=1)
          Group Key: flashcomment.flashnumber
          ->  Index Scan using flashcomment_ndx01 on flashcomment  (cost=0.43..4435.68 rows=3601 width=22) (actual time=3.861..18.628 rows=713 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((flashnumber)::text = ANY ('{2020022601503,2020022601502,2020022601498,2020022601497,2020022601496,2020022601495,2020022601494,2020022601493,2020022601492,2020022601491,2020022601490,2020022620200219007292020021900630,2020021900629,2020021900628}'::text[]))
                Filter: (is_parent = 'N'::bpchar)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..40732.12 rows=2 width=322) (actual time=3.919..15366.603 rows=532 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (upper((fc.stamp_userid)::text) = upper((up.user_id)::text))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 19483968
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..39103.24 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=3.897..34.879 rows=532 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..71.72 rows=3586 width=90) (actual time=3.879..23.038 rows=532 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using flashcomment_ndx01 on flashcomment fc  (cost=0.43..10.87 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=0.012..0.016 rows=1 loops=532)
                    Index Cond: ((flashnumber)::text = (t.flashnumber)::text)
                    Filter: ((is_parent = 'N'::bpchar) AND (t.mx_gmttime = stamp_gmttime))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
        ->  Seq Scan on user_profile up  (cost=0.00..1000.86 rows=35886 width=23) (actual time=0.003..6.865 rows=36625 loops=532)
Planning time: 3.728 ms
Execution time: 15371.683 ms
```

If the number of input values is 530

```
Sort  (cost=44660.91..44660.91 rows=2 width=322) (actual time=37.383..37.406 rows=530 loops=1)
  Sort Key: fc.flashnumber DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 95kB
  CTE t
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..4473.75 rows=3572 width=22) (actual time=3.922..8.892 rows=530 loops=1)
          Group Key: flashcomment.flashnumber
          ->  Index Scan using flashcomment_ndx01 on flashcomment  (cost=0.43..4420.10 rows=3587 width=22) (actual time=3.906..8.644 rows=709 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((flashnumber)::text = ANY ('{2020022601503,2020022601502,2020022601498,2020022601497,2020022601496,2020022601495,2020022601494,2020022601493,2020022601492,2020022601491,2020022601490,2020022601489,2020021900629,2020021900628}'::text[]))
                Filter: (is_parent = 'N'::bpchar)
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=38960.19..40187.14 rows=2 width=322) (actual time=14.613..34.816 rows=530 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (upper((up.user_id)::text) = upper((fc.stamp_userid)::text))
        ->  Seq Scan on user_profile up  (cost=0.00..1000.86 rows=35886 width=23) (actual time=0.008..6.647 rows=36625 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=38960.17..38960.17 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=14.586..14.586 rows=530 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..38960.17 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=3.947..14.203 rows=530 loops=1)
                    ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..71.44 rows=3572 width=90) (actual time=3.925..9.069 rows=530 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using flashcomment_ndx01 on flashcomment fc  (cost=0.43..10.88 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=530)
                          Index Cond: ((flashnumber)::text = (t.flashnumber)::text)
                          Filter: ((is_parent = 'N'::bpchar) AND (t.mx_gmttime = stamp_gmttime))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Planning time: 3.721 ms
Execution time: 37.531 ms
```

Can you help me as to how to improve the performance?

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both queries to the question.

Comment: Try to use "limit" if number of value is fix.

Comment: @Harshit Shah: the values are not fix. Number of values differ as the input values are sent from application interface.